# How to use gruvbox airline theme?

Tags: vim, themes, vimrc

I'm trying to use the gruvbox airline theme with my gruvbox color scheme but there doesn't seem to be an official airline theme for gruvbox.

https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes/tree/master/autoload/airline/themes

In my `~/.vimrc`:

```
colorscheme gruvbox
let g:airline_theme='gruvbox'

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
...
" Status bar
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
...
call plug#end()
```

Produces this error on attempting to open a file with vim:

> Could not resolve airline theme "colors/gruvbox". Themes
>   have been migrated to github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes.

My gruvbox color scheme lives at `~/.vim/colors/gruvbox.vim`.

Comment: What plugin manager are you using ? And have you cloned the main repository ?

Comment: If you install the gruvbox colorscheme plugin, it comes with its own airline theme. Therefore I have not integrated the gruvbox airline theme into the vim-airline-themes repository. Relate issue: [137](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes/pull/137) and related

Comment: I'm using vim-plug, https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, i copied the gruvbox.vim to `~/.vim/colors/gruvbox.vim`.  I have not cloned the whole repo to a location because I'm not sure where the whole repo would go.

Comment: it's so beautiful.  i want this theme so bad.

Comment: Well, then use the gruvbox package and install it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually install the latest gruvbox theme by copying over the required files.  For my configuration, all I needed was the color and autoload files:

```
git clone git@github.com:morhetz/gruvbox.git /tmp/gruvbox
cp /tmp/gruvbox/autoload/* ~/.vim/autoload/
cp /tmp/gruvbox/colors/* ~/.vim/colors/
```

## Using a plugin manager

A more sustainable way to manage the plugin is to add it to your plugin manager.  In my case with vim-plug, this required line:

```
" Colorscheme (includes its own airline theme)
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
```

See also: https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Installation#general

You unfortunately have to STILL MANUALLY ADD THE COLOR CONFIGafter installing.  In my case with vim-plug, after running `:PlugInstall`:

```
mkdir --parents ~/.vim/colors
ln -s ~/.vim/plugged/gruvbox/colors/gruvbox.vim ~/.vim/colors/gruvbox.vim
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc` and it works like a charm

```
" Vim Airline
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
let g:airline_theme='gruvbox'
```

**Note:** You have to run `:PlugInstall` after adding them.